# locate alias with find

Tags: shell, find, function

On small systems where there is no `locate` installed, How would an alias look like that gets the same result as locate?

I can imagine `find` can produce the same output so an alias could look like

```
alias locate="find / -name"
```

But that doesn't seem to work the same as locate:

```
locate test
```

will only find files with the name **exactly** called `test` while locate will find all files containing that.

### Workaround

use:

```
locate *test*
```

Comment: it will work only if you pass on the regular expression.  locate converts filename to `*filename*` by default  , but `find / -name filename` will search for exact filename , so find will require `find / -name *filename*`

Comment: Aliases do not allow (positional) arguments. Use a function instead. Read `man bash` and search for `ALIASES` and/or `FUNCTIONS` for further details

Comment: Really, if you need locate, why not just install it?.  The mlocate implementation is  in the findutils package on savannah.gnu.org, `git://git.savannah.gnu.org/findutils.git`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To improve the huge speed impact on find you could simulate something like locate

```
alias locate="if [ ! -e /tmp/locate.db -a ! -e /tmp/locate.lockdb ]
then touch /tmp/locate.lockdb
trap \"rm /tmp/locate.lockdb; rm /tmp/locate.db; exit\" SIGHUP SIGINT SIGTERM
find /|tee /tmp/locate.db
chmod 666 /tmp/locate.db
rm /tmp/locate.lockdb
elif [ -e /tmp/locate.lockdb ]
then find /
else cat /tmp/locate.db
fi|grep "
```

Of course there is an issue with permissions! It would be better to write some setuid commands for `tee` and `cat` to write the database in super user mode and at a better location but `/tmp`.

A cheap alternative on most single or few user systems would be to write a per-user `locate.db` somewhere near `$HOME`.

Another nice alias is able to update/find. Hmm finally I think this alias works better than the original locate ;)

```
alias relocate="if [ ! -e /tmp/locate.lockdb ]
then rm /tmp/locate.db
fi
locate "
```

**Edit** *I actually though that relocate should just be used like the locate alias above. If you use the relocate without an argument you get an error. The idea is to use `relocate "no file to search for"` if you don't want to search but just update the database.*

Ok, the find must be setuid'ed too. But then you can throw away your locate package.
The `grep` argument should be passed through `sed` to quote the `.` dots.

**NOTE FOR THE NOOBS**: When I'm talking about setuid here **DON'T SET THE SETUID FLAG ON TOOLS LIKE** `tee`,`cat` or `find`. This would be a security breach of your system! What I mean is to write secure alternatives for these simple commands that work in setuid mode and that work in a restricted way, just for the purpose to provide fitted tools for this alias.

Comment: You could name your relocate alilas `updatedb` like the original

Answer (score 4):

```
function locate_f()
{
        find / -path "*$1*" //Edit:path (as Gilles stated)
}
alias locate=locate_f
```

Comment: Or `-path` instead of `-name`, if your find supports it, to be closer to locate which allows `locate foo/bar`.

Comment: To mimic `locate` even more, one can exclude certain folders. Tested on Arch Linux the function becomes: `find / -regextype posix-extended -regex "/(afs|media|mnt|net|sfs|sys|tmp|proc|udev)" -prune -o -path "*$1*" -print`

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
alias locate="find / | grep "
```

That should work exactly as locate - but of course it will be much slower

Comment: Not the same pattern syntax.

Answer (score 1):

**1) Add Alias globally for all users**

```
echo 'alias locate="grep $1 /var/locate/locate.db"' >> /etc/bashrc
```

you could essentially point it to a shell script which you can do more intuitive argument selections... This should be adequate if you're just looking for very simple search.

**2) Add Cron Job to run Daily.**

```
/etc/cron.daily
#!bin/bash
if [[ ! -d /var/locate ]]; then
     mkdir /var/locate
fi
locatedb=/var/locate/locate.db
rm -f $locatedb
for DIRS in `ls /|grep -v "proc"`
do
   find /$DIRS -type f >> $locatedb 2>&1 /dev/null
done
```

You'll have the same results as mlocate w/o installing mlocate... I just tested on CentOS.... and the results are ALMOST exactly identical.

Comment: This is more than just an alias, you need cron also, so this is not the answer to the question. Though this is a nice thing, you created here ;)